# First() method returns wrong string

Tags: c#, linq

How to tell the First method which is part of LINQ library to return proper value. I have something like this:

```
var query = db.SinglePageContent.Where(q => q.Lang == zm1 && q.PageName == zm2).Select(s => new { s.Content});

//var reqUrl = query.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Content);
ViewBag.requestUrl = query.First();
```

and now the `ViewBag.requestUrl` has value `{ Content = bla bla bla }`, but I want to have only "bla bla bla". I just don't know how to get there to only retrieve value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating new anonymous class with `new { }`

use this instead

```
var query = db.SinglePageContent.Where(q => q.Lang == zm1 && q.PageName == zm2)
    .Select(s => s.Content);
```

Comment: sorry about delay but I was afk and couldn't mark this answer in less than 15 min from posting it